# Efficient way redis set member update

Tags: java, node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a redis set. This set can store 20 members maximum(added with`SADD` command).
My problem is ; I need to update that members when needed. Members need that modification maximum 10 times for every member. Set members are json as a string. There is only solutoin on my mind nor, get all members update and recreate that set again. But it seems iditoic.

I know there is `ZADD` sorted set with its score support it seems suitable also I need to update score like data in json , but i just wonder Is there any method updating members in efficient way, or is updating member not acceptable on redis way ?

*Note: Redis datastore is using by both node.js and java clients.*

Comment: Have you considered using MongoDB?

Comment: @thepirat000 already using on another layer.

Comment: The use case seems to fit. See the MongoDB's [field update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/)

Comment: @thepirat000 yes it seems, but in a premature application I can't change this layer's operations to mongodb operations. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set members themselves are immutable - you can add new members or remove existing ones. That's it.

Given that a set is an unordered collection of unique members, consider the possible outcomes were set members theoretically modifiable when the new value for a member:

1. is identical to the old value - no change to the set
2. already exists in the set - equivalent to deleting that member
3. isn't 1 or 2 - equivalent to deleting the member and adding a new one

Comment: thanks for your reply , I have also thought about third option but it seems not suitable for multi-thread application. So I decided to create a new temporary set to make relation with existing set. May you give specific advice Is it a good way? Thanks.

Comment: No need - use a MULTI/EXEC block or a short Lua script to make the SREM and SADD atomic and prevent any threading-related race conditions.