# Redis - Update Set Members

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I currently have a redis set like so,

```
redis in01apv16:6379> smembers key1
1) "{property1:value4,property2:value5,property3:value6}"
2) "{property1:value1,property2:value2,property3:value3}"

redis in01apv16:6379> smembers key2
1) "{property1:value1,property2:value2,property3:value3}"

redis in01apv16:6379> smembers key3
1) "{property1:value1,property2:value2,property3:value3}"
2) "{property1:value7,property2:value8,property3:value9}"
```

Lets assume I need to update a set member in `key3` for whichever member has property1=value7. How do I do this?

One approach I found was read all the members in the set, and perform a `SREM` on that particular set member. But this seems too tedious, is there a better way?

*Side Note: I'm Using StackExchange.Redis (In case there is a way to do this from the driver directly)*

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32927213/3160475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't any way to update the value of key in Redis because of underlying architecture. you should remove the old value using "srem" and add another member using "sadd" command.

> But this seems too tedious, is there a better way?

I don't think so, it's better to read about Redis architecture. what is important in this scenario is the complexity of "srem" and "sadd" commands which is O(1) if one item at a time added or removed and O(N) if multiple items have been added or removed from set .