# Incrementing a member in Redis sorted set

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a Redis sorted set where the score is a Unix timestamp and the member is a counter. Is there a way to increment this counter effectively? It seems Redis only provides functionality for incrementing the score.

Answer (score 1):

Members of sets (sorted or not) are immutable - there is no way/reason to update them: [Efficient way redis set member update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927213/efficient-way-redis-set-member-update/32928210#32928210)